# Android Slide View with Single or overlapping Background

Tags: android, background, android-viewpager, slide

I need to reproduce this Menu in Android. -> [MenuVideo sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43532071/files/Main%20Menu.mov) 
How would i implement this the best way!??Normally i'd use a `ViewPager`.
But how would i show parts of the next views like in view 2 & 3 in the video. **Notice how you can see part of the text of the other views**.
The customer wants users to see that it is scrollable by showing a little of the next views!

How would i give the `HorizontalScrollView` that bouncing behaviour. All i got as a resource is the wide background png **including the text**.!
 How would you solve this and make the menu from the video in Android?! I mean, it's doable on ios.

Comment: Maybe you should use `HorizontalScrollView` not `ViewPager`

Comment: @Procurares horizontalscrollview doesn't bounce

Comment: yea, i figured that out by now aswell. @CQM what would you use?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a horizontal scrollview that is customized to show content from pages at both ends. Also the touch events should be handled properly so it snaps to page ends.

I had a similar requirement in one of my projects and pushed code to GitHub at [SnappingScrollView](https://github.com/rajivnarayana/SnappingScrollView) so it could be of help to someone.

Please let me know if it is of some use.

You could alternately use a pager adapter with custom page width but it would not show content from previous page.

Comment: thx, i'll try it asap and reopen and award bounty if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Viewpager with a background split into 4 drawable assets. The viewpager will load them based on their position in an arraylist.

You need a plain image asset without the text in it. The text needs to be separate images that are part of your individual views. It will be difficult / near impossible to predict how different android devices will scale the image, so you can't just place invisible hotlinks

Comment: First off, thx for the response. The viewpager was my first idea aswell, since its made for these kind of things. But will it be possible to see Parts of the other views, like in the video?i.e
i'm on View 3, and see the edges of view 2 and 4? I know its stupid, but the customer wants what the customer wants

Comment: Oh and your right about the text, i already told the designer i need it seperated.

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r when you scroll on the viewpager you will see parts of the adjacent views. you can also programmatically scroll viewpager views as well with fake scroll

Comment: Thx, i'm aware of that. what i mean is when it's not beeing scrolled. Like in the vid, you can see a bit of the text of the next view.

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r I see now, in the 2nd view the text bleeds over. I'm not aware of a way to do that in android. If the text was part of the background this would be possible , but then you couldn't be guaranteed to be able to click on it with invisible buttons because they would be placed differently by other devices

Comment: ok. And how would I do it when the text is embedded in the BG?

Comment: i'll clarify that with the overlapping Views in the Title

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r look into modifying this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator it is a library for adding the little circles at the bottom of the viewpager so you know which page you are on, I think this could be used for a background too

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r But I otherwise haven't seen overlapping textviews that bleed out the side of a parent view

Comment: Thx for the input. Fortunatly the indicators arent a requirement. And i Dont have to implement them necessarily. But its still good to have and i will probably use it! Unfortunatly the Overlapping text is. Since it has been done on IOS. I'll dig into this some more, i might even put up a Bounty when the waiting period is over. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do:

```
yourViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //return whatever fragment you want;
    }
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.8f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return the count;
    }
});
```

Comment: thx, i'll try it asap and reopen and award bounty if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager`or `ViewFlipper` i have added both links below.

ViewPagers source their views from PagerAdapters which give you have full control over the reuse and recycling of the views. A PagerAdapter implementation called FragmentPagerAdapter is provided to facilitate the use of Fragments in a ViewPager;

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        … />
```

Support demos:

```
  public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }
```

FragmentPagerAdapter will detach each fragment as you swipe through the list, but keep them in memory so they can simply be reattached when the user swipes back.

For more info try this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

OR may be you can go for `ViewFlipper`

```
public class ViewFlipperActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener,
        OnTouchListener {

    private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewflipper_layout);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
        mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mViewFlipper.startFlipping();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 0) {
            //mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        } else {
            //mViewFlipper.showNext();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

}
```

ViewFilpper control system comes with one of the controls, the main switch and set in the same screen animation, and Autoplay, usage is as above,Thus [this](http://www.verydemo.com/demo_c131_i6929.html) example is what you need!!!!

Comment: thx, i'll try it asap and reopen and award bounty if it works